# Where is my wwwhisper admin page in my Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, wwwhisper

I've successfully installed WWWhisper in my Heroku app.  I can log in and see the site.  But I can't find any documentation on where adding other e-mails and permissions would be.  Like the admin page they display in pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.  According to https://github.com/wrr/wwwhisper/blob/master/wwwhisper_service/settings.py#L12 it's at `/wwwhisper/admin/`

Comment: For a reference this is also documented here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/wwwhisper#using-with-ruby-on-rails-or-other-rack-based-applications-push-the-configuration-and-test-the-authorization